# CXF Interceptor phases being skipped for missing phase declaration

Tags: spring, cxf, objenesis

Been working on this one for a bit and haven't had any luck.

I'm in the process of upgrading from Spring 3.2.9 to 4.2.6. My first step was upgrading to cxf-core 3.1.6, which I did with no issues to the app.

When upgrading all spring dependencies I am running into an issue with the interceptor setup though. Here's the basics:

**Interceptor**

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>{

private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyInterceptor.class);

public MyInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    addAfter(HolderInInterceptor.class.getName());
}

@PostConstruct
public void display() {
    logger.warn(this.getPhase());
}


@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    ....
```

**cxfContext.xml**

```
<bean id="contentInInterceptor" class="com.MyInterceptor">
</bean>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="contentInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>


</cxf:bus>
```

as well as it being added in web.xml. When running I see the logged information showing the interceptor is created with a phase of pre-invoke (I added this to verify I'm not going crazy). But when calling the service, the PhaseInterceptor chain is skipping the interceptor for not declaring a phase:

Logs:

> 2016-05-31 16:08:28,208 [localhost-startStop-1] [] WARN 
>   c.MyInterceptor - pre-invoke
>
> 2016-05-31 16:10:14,552
>   [http-bio-8080-exec-1] [] WARN  o.a.c.p.PhaseInterceptorChain -
>   Skipping interceptor
>   com.MyInterceptor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1afa70e1: Phase declaration
>   is missing.

This is intercepting a jaxws server call. Again, all I've changed that has caused the issues is updating to the latest version of Spring. It almost appears as though cxf is using a separate interceptor that was never generated from the bean.

**EDIT**

I believe I've found the issue, but again I'm not sure where the fix would be. Spring 4 proxy does not call the constructor twice when creating the proxy (i.e. it creates the raw bean using the constructor, but the CGLIB created proxy of the bean does not call the constructor). This causes the phase of the interceptor to be null.

I changed around my @PostContsruct on the class to confirm this:

```
    @PostConstruct
public void display() {
    logger.warn(this.getPhase());
    MyInterceptor myInterceptor = (MyInterceptor) appContext.getBean("contentInInterceptor");
    logger.warn("Bean phase is: " + myInterceptor.getPhase());
}
```

Logs show bean creation's phase versus proxy's phase:

> 2016-06-01 10:36:52,829 [localhost-startStop-1] [] WARN  c.MyInterceptor - pre-invoke
>
> 2016-06-01 10:36:52,839 [localhost-startStop-1] [] WARN  c.MyInterceptor - Bean phase is: null

Comment: Thx for this post, as I faced to the same issue today.
8-hours later, implementing my own *IN* interceptor, without extending **AbstractPhaseInterceptor**, interceptor was finally called again. For other people, this issue appear just after migrating from spring 3.2.x to 5.1.x PS: I apologize for this message (versus a comment) but I haven't the required reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured out a way around this for now, but it isn't the greatest implementation.

Basically what I ended up having to do was create an abstract class that implemented PhaseInterceptor and all of those implemented methods were set as abstract.

Then my interceptors extended from that class and had their own phase/id/before/after variables. It appears as though there may be an issue with Spring's bean proxy setup when variables are not available in the bean's direct class. At least that's what I'm finding in this case.

Again, not sure if it's the best solution, but this makes the interceptors work again.

Answer (score 0):

You said that interceptor is intercepting jaxws server call. So my assumption is, it is outgoing call.

`Phase.PRE_INVOKE` is for incoming message. Use other phases like  `Phase.PRE_STREAM` for outgoing message

For documentation of phases please see

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. My app has a jaxws server. I'm calling the server through SoapUI, so the message is inbound.